# Escape Quote sign for vimrc

Tags: vim

I tried to map `<Leader> p` (in insert mode) to `Ctrl+R "` command in my vimrc. However, as the `"` sign is the comment sign for vim, I just can't get it to work

I tried:
`inoremap <Leader>p <c-r>"` and
`inoremap <Leader>p <c-r>\"`
, but both of them don't really give me the register conntent of `"`. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

From Vim's manual (`:help map-comments`):

> It is not possible to put a comment after these commands, because the ' " ' character is considered to be part of the {lhs} or {rhs}.

So in your case there is no need to escape the `"` character. Thus the first map that you provided:

```
inoremap <Leader>p <c-r>"
```

should work. For example, consider the text:

```
one two three
```

typing `yy` in normal mode will copy the line. Then type `A` to go to the end of the line in insert mode.  Typing `<leader>p` results in:

```
one two three    one two three
```

If this does not work verify that you are really typing the `<leader>` key (use `:echo mapleader` to see the leader key). Also check that the contents of the `"` register are indeed `one two three` (to do this use `:register "`).